Can't change Label from script
I've set up a project in Godot 4 with a Node2D scene that has a Label as a child. I put [placeholder text] in the text field in the Inspector for the label.  I can't change the text from the attached script using the following code.
func _ready():
    $Label.text = "Message from GDScript"

Also tried:
func _ready():
    var myLabel = $Label
    myLabel.text = "Message from GDScript"

Everything I've seen in the documentation and other questions people have posted about labels indicates these should work.  But when I run the scene it displays [placeholder text] instead of Message from GDScript.
Thanks for you help.

SOLVED.  I wiped the project and created a completely new project and now the code above works.  Not sure what changed but it's working.
